# A variation of the subset sum problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, np-hardness

The subset sum problem is NP Complete. I was wondering if the following variation can be proved to be NP Complete :

The cardinality of set of integers is $m$.
And each element of the set is between $1$ and $m^2$. Repetitions are allowed.
The objective is to find a subset that would sum up to a given sum.

This seems to be as hard as the subset sum itself, but i cant come up with a reduction that would prove my conjecture.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic; not a research-level question. This seems to be a variant that is [easy to solve using dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Comment: so solvable using dp implies a polynomial time algorithm right?

Comment: No, but in *this* case it is a polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: I don't know if you have read the FAQ but this site is for **research-level questions** in **theoretical computer science**. Please refer to the FAQ for further information about the scope of cstheory. Closing the question as off-topic.